# Changing file icon images

Tags: check-out, file-icons

I'd like to accomplish two things:

1. I want to change the color on the "checked out" arrow from green to red to increase visibility.
2. I'd like to know how to modify the icons associated with different extensions.  For instance, all .pdf files currently have a blank white page for an icon and I'd like to make it something more recognizable.

Do I need to do these things programatically?  Are there image files buried somewhere in the back end that I can just modify and save?  Do I need to get cozy with some CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You can replace the icon "CheckOutToOverlay.gif". You find it under \14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES. If you want to do it "right" you probably need to write code that replaces the icon on every server. But it should work by replacing it manually -until an update/service pack overwrites you changes.

2) You can change the association to the icons via the "DOCICON.xml". You find it under 14\template\xml.